# Widget Logic code for different PMP membership levels

Tags: widgets, code

I'm using both **Paid Memberships Pro** and **Widget Logic** plugins.

In PMP, I set up 2 membership levels - one free ( id# = 3) , one paid (id# = 1)

With Widget Logic, I'd like to have the custom sidebar menu only show up to the paid member

Any ideas on how to shortcode this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pmpro_hasMembershipLevel(6)
```

Or whatever the level is, 1,2,3,4 etc. Mine was 6.